# How to make python's argparse generate Non-English text?

Tags: python, internationalization, argparse

The **argparse** module "automatically generates help and usage messages". I can give Non-English names to the arguments and provide Non-English help texts; but the help output then becomes a mixture of at least two languages, because terms like `usage`, `positional arguments`, `optional arguments` and `show this help message and exit` are automatically generated in English.

How can I replace this English output with translations?

Preferably, I would like to provide the translations within the script, so that the script generates the same output wherever it is started.

**Edit:** Based on the answer by Jon-Eric, here an example with his solution:

```
import gettext

def Übersetzung(Text):
    Text = Text.replace("usage", "Verwendung")
    Text = Text.replace("show this help message and exit",
                        "zeige diese Hilfe an und tue nichts weiteres")
    Text = Text.replace("error:", "Fehler:")
    Text = Text.replace("the following arguments are required:",
                        "Die folgenden Argumente müssen angegeben werden:")
    return Text
gettext.gettext = Übersetzung

import argparse

Parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
Parser.add_argument("Eingabe")
Argumente = Parser.parse_args()

print(Argumente.Eingabe)
```

saved as `Beispiel.py` gives with `python3 Beispiel.py -h` the following help output:

```
Verwendung: Beispiel.py [-h] Eingabe

positional arguments:
  Eingabe

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  zeige diese Hilfe an und tue nichts weiteres
```

Comment: Show examples and code please.

Comment: You could define your own `argument_groups` if you want to change the names of `positional arguments` and `optional arguments`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank you for this suggestion. Jon-Eric's gettext.gettext solution works for those names, too; I just didn't replace them in the above example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, from [this post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-August/629396.html) by Peter Otten:

> I don't know much about gettext, but the following suggests that most
>   strings in argparse are properly wrapped:
>
> ```
> $ cat localize_argparse.py
>
> import gettext
>
> def my_gettext(s):
>     return s.upper()
> gettext.gettext = my_gettext
>
> import argparse
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>     parser.add_argument("-V", action="version")
>     args = parser.parse_args()
>
> $ python localize_argparse.py -h USAGE: localize_argparse.py [-h] [-V]
>
> OPTIONAL ARGUMENTS:   -h, --help  SHOW THIS HELP MESSAGE AND EXIT   -V
> show program's version number and exit
> ```
>
> The workaround for the "-V" option would be to add the help message
>   explicitly
>
> ```
> parser.add_argument("-V", ..., help=_("show..."))
> ```
>
> You still have to provide all translations yourself.

Comment: Thank you! That does it. It seems to be important to import argparse only after gettext.gettext is redefined.

Answer (score 12):

`argparse` uses the [`gettext` API inspired by GNU gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gnu-gettext-api).
You can use this API to integrate your translation of `argparse` in a relatively clean manner.

To do so, call the following code before `argparse` outputs any text (but possibly after `import argparse`):

```
import gettext

# Use values that suit your project instead of 'argparse' and 'path/to/locale'
gettext.bindtextdomain('argparse', 'path/to/locale')
gettext.textdomain('argparse')
```

In order for this solution to work, your translation of `argparse` must be located at `path/to/locale/ll/LC_MESSAGES/argparse.mo` where `ll` is the code of the current language (for example `de`; can be configured for example by setting the environment variable `LANGUAGE`).

### How do you generate the `.mo` file?

1. `pygettext --default-domain=argparse /usr/local/lib/python3.5/argparse.py`

   - Use the actual location of `argparse.py`
   - Creates the file `argparse.pot`
2. `cp argparse.pot argparse-ll.po`

   - Use an actual language code instead of `ll`
3. Fill in the missing translation strings in `argparse-ll.po`
4. `msgfmt argparse-ll.po -o locale/ll/LC_MESSAGES/argparse.mo`

See [`gettext` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules) for details about creating `.mo` file.

I have published these instructions in more detail in [README.md](https://github.com/filipbartek/argparse-cs/blob/master/README.md) of my [Czech translation of `argparse`](https://github.com/filipbartek/argparse-cs).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with French translation, where one creates a conversion dict that holds the translation for the encountered English keywords

```
def convertArgparseMessages(s):
    subDict = \
    {'positional arguments':'Arguments positionnels',
    'optional arguments':'Arguments optionnels',
    'show this help message and exit':'Affiche ce message et quitte'}
    if s in subDict:
        s = subDict[s]
    return s
gettext.gettext = convertArgparseMessages
import argparse
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python module to translate all messages emitted by argparse. It is intended for a quick and dirty translation to only one other language (French in my case, but feel free to adjust that for your own language). For a more industrial multilingual approach, look at the excellent Filip Bartek solution.

```py
"""
This module is like argparse but in french. 
Import it and use it like you would use argparse.

DIRECTIVES:
First copy-paste this code in a separate new file named french_argparse.py
Put this new file beside your main.py file in the same top project folder.
Then in the main.py file, import it like this:

>>> import french_argparse as argparse
"""

import gettext

#################################################################################################################
# The following translations are in French, but feel free to replace them with your own
# Many messages are even not translated, because they seems to be more intended for the programmer than the user.
# Phrases were extracted from the code at (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py)
# On October 2019
#################################################################################################################

__TRANSLATIONS = {
    'ambiguous option: %(option)s could match %(matches)s': 'option ambiguë: %(option)s parmi %(matches)s',
    'argument "-" with mode %r': 'argument "-" en mode %r',
    'cannot merge actions - two groups are named %r': 'cannot merge actions - two groups are named %r',
    "can't open '%(filename)s': %(error)s": "can't open '%(filename)s': %(error)s",
    'dest= is required for options like %r': 'dest= is required for options like %r',
    'expected at least one argument': 'au moins un argument est attendu',
    'expected at most one argument': 'au plus un argument est attendu',
    'expected one argument': 'un argument est nécessaire',
    'ignored explicit argument %r': 'ignored explicit argument %r',
    'invalid choice: %(value)r (choose from %(choices)s)': 'choix invalide: %(value)r (parmi %(choices)s)',
    'invalid conflict_resolution value: %r': 'invalid conflict_resolution value: %r',
    'invalid option string %(option)r: must start with a character %(prefix_chars)r':
        'invalid option string %(option)r: must start with a character %(prefix_chars)r',
    'invalid %(type)s value: %(value)r': 'valeur invalide de type %(type)s: %(value)r',
    'mutually exclusive arguments must be optional': 'mutually exclusive arguments must be optional',
    'not allowed with argument %s': "pas permis avec l'argument %s",
    'one of the arguments %s is required': 'au moins un argument requis parmi %s',
    'optional arguments': 'arguments optionnels',
    'positional arguments': 'arguments positionnels',
    "'required' is an invalid argument for positionals": "'required' is an invalid argument for positionals",
    'show this help message and exit': 'afficher ce message et quitter',
    'unrecognized arguments: %s': 'argument non reconnu: %s',
    'unknown parser %(parser_name)r (choices: %(choices)s)': 'unknown parser %(parser_name)r (choices: %(choices)s)',
    'usage: ': 'usage: ',
    '%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n': '%(prog)s: erreur: %(message)s\n',
    '%r is not callable': '%r is not callable',
}


gettext.gettext = lambda text: __TRANSLATIONS[text] or text

##############################################################################
# Now import all argparse functionalities inside this module.
#
#   NB Many linters don't like the following line of code so we have disabled
#   warnings for pylint, flake8 and PyCharm
##############################################################################

# pylint: disable=all
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from argparse import *                  # noqa
```

Comment: A beta version of a project giving French translations for the argparse module is currently available on Github (https://github.com/s-ball/i18nparse).

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem.
Almost all messages will translated properly doing as described in post 5, but not the help messages added with `parser.add_argument()`.
You can solve the problem by using non-class-based `gettext` for argparse and class-based `gettext` for the app.
Have a look at app3.py in https://github.com/jmo3300/py01_i18n_01